# How to validate error message using c# in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am struggling to validate an empty `EditorFor` using `Data-Annotation`, have tried using jquery on a client side. Somehow I feel it's better to validate it from the back end than front end. Have a look and help me to improve my logic error. The idea I want this error to validate when user leaves the `@EditorFor()` showing error image.

```
// Model
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
public string Email { get; set; }
        

//View
script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () {
        //When the blur event occurs from your Textbox (you lose focus)
        $('#textEmail').blur(function () {
            var email = document.getElementById("textEmail").value;
            var expr = /^([\w-\.]+)@@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
            if (!expr.test(email)) {
                alert("Invalid email address.");
            }
            else {
                alert("Ok");
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved without JQuery by using MVC's Data Annotation properly.

For data annotation, write error message above the property as below:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Some other annotations are also available along with Required annotation. To validate the valid email address below annotation can be used:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Invalid email address")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: Imran i have used this logic just now im not getting any error message when leaving my @EditorFor(model=>model.RegForm.Email). Must have @ValidateErrorMessage as well on the Razor? Please advice me.

Comment: Have you added this jquery reference for data annotation: jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js ?

Comment: On View @Script...? No i dont have

Comment: Yes on view page add the scripts for validation with data annotation:
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/assets/js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
follow your own file paths.